# Dim/dark screen back after latest update [Ubuntu 12.04]

Tags: 12.04, updates, laptop

I booted a few minutes ago and everything was fine, update manager notified me about new updates so I decided to install them, and then poof, dim/dark screen is back in action.

I did update grub, I did tried to remve fglrx but terminal said I don't even have it installed and the "classical" fix I used is the

`sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=01`

It does work, but only till I reboot, I had same problem but I added this code before exit 0 from /etc/rc.local [`gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`] now it's still here but it doesn't work. I also tried nomode set before booting, it resulted in a crash.

Any ideas how to fix it? And I would also want to know if I can get completely the rid of this thing? It always came back when the computer was idle or when I tried to run things in full screen mode.

Other info: I run it on an Acer Aspire 5732Z with Intel GMA 4500M (graphics accelerator) if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just press buttons <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> while booting starts and that's it!

If its for acer laptop.

Comment: oddly enough that worked for me!

Comment: Do you need to press the keys on every boot, or is the setting kept?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having problems with suspend / resume in addition to the boot problem with a dimmed screen. The following 2 lines updated in `/etc/default/grub` fixed both of my issues.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Be sure to replace `vendor` with `your_machine_vendor` and run `sudo update-grub`